# {Methcomp} – Deming / orthogonal regression – goodness of fit + confidence intervals

Tags: r, linear-regression, orthogonal, goodness-of-fit

A question following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31862766/linear-regression-using-lm-surprised-by-the-result). I have the following data:

- x1, disease symptom
- y1, another disease symptom

I fitted the x1/y1 data with a Deming regression with vr (or sdr) option set to 1. In other words, the regression is a Total Least Squares regression, i.e. orthogonal regression. See previous post for the graph.

```
x1=c(24.0,23.9,23.6,21.6,21.0,20.8,22.4,22.6,
 21.6,21.2,19.0,19.4,21.1,21.5,21.5,20.1,20.1,
 20.1,17.2,18.6,21.5,18.2,23.2,20.4,19.2,22.4,
 18.8,17.9,19.1,17.9,19.6,18.1,17.6,17.4,17.5,
 17.5,25.2,24.4,25.6,24.3,24.6,24.3,29.4,29.4,
 29.1,28.5,27.2,27.9,31.5,31.5,31.5,27.8,31.2,
 27.4,28.8,27.9,27.6,26.9,28.0,28.0,33.0,32.0,
 34.2,34.0,32.6,30.8)

y1=c(100.0,95.5,93.5,100.0,98.5,99.5,34.8,
 45.8,47.5,17.4,42.6,63.0,6.9,12.1,30.5,
 10.5,14.3,41.1, 2.2,20.0,9.8,3.5,0.5,3.5,5.7,
 3.1,19.2,6.4, 1.2, 4.5, 5.7, 3.1,19.2, 6.4,
 1.2,4.5,81.5,70.5,91.5,75.0,59.5,73.3,66.5,
 47.0,60.5,47.5,33.0,62.5,87.0,86.0,77.0,
 86.0,83.0,78.5,83.0,83.5,73.0,69.5,82.5,78.5,
 84.0,93.5,83.5,96.5,96.0,97.5)   

x11()
plot(x1,y1,xlim=c(0,35),ylim=c(0,100))
library(MethComp)
dem_reg <- Deming(x1, y1)
abline(dem_reg[1:2], col = "green")
```

I would like to know how much x1 helps to predict y1:

- normally, I’d go for a R-squared, but it does not seem [to be relevant](http://www.quora.com/Should-a-Deming-regression-include-an-R-2-value); although another mathematician told me he thinks a R-squared may be appropriate. And this page suggests to calculate a [Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/96069/goodness-of-fit-value-from-orthogonal-distance-regression), which is R I believe?
- partially related, there is possibly a [tolerance interval](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44219/tolerance-interval-for-deming-regression). I could calculated it with R ({tolerance} package or code shown in the post), but it is not exactly what I am searching for.

Does someone know how to calculate a goodness of fit for Deming regression, using R? I looked at MetchComp pdf but could not find it (perhaps missed it though).

**EDIT: following Gaurav's answers about confidence interval: R code**

Firstly: confidence intervals for parameters

```
library(mcr)
MCR_reg=mcreg(x1,y1,method.reg="Deming",error.ratio=1,method.ci="analytical")
getCoefficients(MCR_reg)
```

Secondly: confidence intervals for predicted values

```
# plot of data
x11()
plot(x1,y1,xlim=c(0,35),ylim=c(0,100))

# Deming regression using functions from {mcr}
library(mcr)     MCR_reg=mcreg(x1,y1,method.reg="Deming",error.ratio=1,method.ci="analytical")
MCR_intercept=getCoefficients(MCR_reg)[1,1]
MCR_slope=getCoefficients(MCR_reg)[2,1]

# CI for predicted values
x_to_predict=seq(0,35)
predicted_values=MCResultAnalytical.calcResponse(MCR_reg,x_to_predict,alpha=0.05)
CI_low=predicted_values[,4]
CI_up=predicted_values[,5]

# plot regression line and CI for predicted values
abline(MCR_intercept,MCR_slope, col="red")
lines(x_to_predict,CI_low,col="royalblue",lty="dashed")
lines(x_to_predict,CI_up,col="royalblue",lty="dashed")

# comments
text(7.5,60, "Deming regression", col="red")
text(7.5,40, "Confidence Interval for", col="royalblue")
text(7.5,35, "Predicted values - 95%", col="royalblue")
```

**EDIT 2**
Topic moved to Cross Validated:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/167907/deming-orthogonal-regression-measuring-goodness-of-fit

Comment: does *confidence interval for predicted values*  mean the same as *prediction interval*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many proposed methods to calculate goodness of fit and tolerance intervals for Deming Regression but none of them widely accepted. The conventional methods we use for OLS regression may not make sense. This is an area of active research. I don't think there many R-packages which will help you compute that since not many mathematicians agree on any particular method. Most methods for calculating intervals are based on Resampling techniques.

However you can check out the 'mcr' package for intervals...
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mcr/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what I thought, since I could not find much on the Internet. So you confirm the Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient is not usable? Following your advice, and to get at least something to work, I tried a confidence intervals in {mcr}, namely the function mc.analytical.ci(). But it doesn't work, the function seems unknown. Any hint? The code being `library(mcr) mc.analytical.ci(-187.3,9.86,3.41,3.41,length(x1),5)`

Comment: Most functions in this package cannot be called directly. You have to use them along with mcreg() function. Check out the description for mcreg() in the document. PCC will not tell you anything relevant.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't see how to do that. I used `mcreg` then `getCoefficients`, but don't see how to use these coeffs in `mc.analytical.ci`.

Comment: What you need to do is while using mcreg() function you have to set the argument `method.ci = c( "analytical")` inside the function. This will give you the CI using "analytical" method. There are other methods of "bootstrap","jackknife", and "nestedbootstrap" for calculating CI. Don't use a separate mc.analytical.ci() code. Just mcreg() with CI arguments will be enough to get you the output with CI.

Comment: Ok I see now, we get the confidence interval for the parameters. Thanks. Any way to get the confidence interval for predicted values? Something similar to `predict`with `interval=confidence`. This all conversation may be off-topic though, I may create another topic to group answers.

Comment: I think you can use MCResultAnalytical.calcResponse() for that with specifying the alpha for confidence interval. I have not tried it myself though.

Comment: Many thanks! I grouped your answers in the original post.

Comment: I accepted your answer. Since there is no "golden gun" technique to calculate goodness of fit, I asked the question on Cross Validated. Many thanks for your time.